# Print priview in Eclipse

Tags: jsp

I am working on Eclipse 3.2 tomcat server 5.5 software, using jsp programming language.I want to have a print button that will print preview first before the printing process could be occurs.Beside that, How can I ensure that full page will be printed? because when I print,there were missing space and words on the printed paper.Hopefully you all can give some advice or examples. thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Print Preview is a feature of a browser, so you can just use it.
  For example *Firefox*

[image]

- If you want to *Print Preview* button in your JSP code then you can use [jQuery Print Preview plugin](https://github.com/etimbo/jquery-print-preview-plugin/blob/master/README.md).
  See [here demo](http://etimbo.github.io/jquery-print-preview-plugin/example/index.html)
- [This is the article](http://www.mindstick.com/Articles/83e5fed0-9db4-4b35-b34b-cca8de153655/?Print%20and%20Print%20Preview%20separately%20using%20HTML,%20CSS%20and%20JavaScript) which designs *Print Preview* button using HTML, CSS and JavaScript
- Wonderful [article](http://alistapart.com/article/goingtoprint) on printing a page.